# JavaScript - merging results from two API calls

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, rxjs

I have a straightforward Angular component (Ionic) which makes:

1. an API call to get some data (returned as an Observable) and
2. gets data from a SQLite database stored on the device (returned as a Promise)

I am trying to merge the two results.

Here is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { merge } from 'rxjs';
import { Fact } from '../fact';
import { Label } from '../label';
import { DashboardService } from '../services/dashboard.service';
import { DatabaseService } from '../services/database.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.page.scss'],
})
export class DashboardPage implements OnInit {
  rows: Fact[];
  labels: Label[];

  constructor(
    private dashboardService: DashboardService,
    private database: DatabaseService
  ) {
    this.refreshDashboard();
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  refreshDashboard() {
    console.log('refreshing...');
    this.getDashboardData();
    // Get labels
    this.database
      .createDatabase()
      .then(() => {
        this.getLabels();
      })
      .then(() => {            
        console.log(this.rows.length); // ******* UNDEFINED *******
        console.log(this.labels.length); // ******* UNDEFINED *******
      });
  }

  // Coming from an API call, which returns an Observable
  getDashboardData() {
    this.dashboardService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.rows = data;
    });
  }

  // Coming from local SQLite database
  getLabels() {
    this.database
      .getLabels()
      .then((data) => {
        this.labels = [];
        if (data.rows.length > 0) {
          for (let i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
            this.labels.push(data.rows.item(i));
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        alert('There was an error: ' + e);
      });
  }

  // mergeResults()
}
```

I cannot figure out how to ensure that the two variables **rows** and **labels** have been populated before I can use them inside mergeResults().

Comment: You need to *return* promises, and make them part of the same chain.

Comment: The getLabels() function inside my service (database: DatabaseService), returns the promise. I am using it inside the component's getLabel() method (sorry for using the same names, it's probably confusing) to populate the labels variable. If I use *ngIf in the template, I can check that the two variables have been populated. Need to figure out how to check them inside the class. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: But the getLabels method in the component (yes that's confusing) doesn't return a promise, nor does the callback where it's invoked, so that's not part of the promise chain in refreshDashboard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`then()` must be nested when the order matters. So

```
  dosomething1.then( ()=> {
     dosomething2.then( () => {
       dosomething3.then( () => {
         console.log("hey");
                       })
                     })
                   })
```

In your case that would mean

```
 refreshDashboard() {
    console.log('refreshing...');
    this.getDashboardData();
    // Get labels
    this.database
      .createDatabase()
      .then(() => {
        this.getLabels();
      })
      .then(() => {  <---This here has no use at all. Nothing returns a promise here           
      });
  }

  // Coming from an API call, which returns an Observable
  getDashboardData() {
    this.dashboardService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.rows = data;
    });
  }

  // Coming from local SQLite database
  getLabels() {
    this.database
      .getLabels()
      .then((data) => {
        this.labels = [];
        if (data.rows.length > 0) {
          for (let i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
            this.labels.push(data.rows.item(i));
          }
        }
        console.log(this.rows.length); // here you expect values to be ready
        console.log(this.labels.length); // here you expect values to be ready
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        alert('There was an error: ' + e);
      });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was making some conceptual mistakes. Much appreciated.

Comment: `.then` does *not* have to be nested, that way you just end up back in "callback hell". You could rewrite that first example to `dosomething1.then(() => dosomething2).then(() => dosomething3).then(() => console.log("hey"))`, which is much flatter; the crucial thing is to return the promise from the callback to make it part of the chain.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you please provide a concrete example of sequential http calls using that technique? Not with general return promise, please explain how to make http calls and return the promise back to the next. thanks

Comment: Instead of just doing a `.then` inside the already existing `then`-closure, just return the function call as @jonrsharpe suggests. _That_ will return the promise back to the next.